# Extracting String using regex

Tags: regex

I am using a HTA Application I wrote for our help desk to take notes.

I've been using regex (Best I can) to CTRL+A our ticket pop up and click parse on my app to fill out information

I need to find `"TICKET - T00000000.0000 - Account Security (Company Name...)"` and only grab the "Account Security" section. or for future grab whatever is between the 2nd - and the (

Any suggestions would be grand

here is an example what I've tried and what I am using

```
try { 
$(".problem_description", context).val(clipdata.match(/TICKET -.+[)]/)[0]);
 } 
catch (e) {
}
```

Update
I have tried a few of the suggestions here but the results still seem to give me the entire string or error out in my script.

[image]

Comment: Try `match(/TICKET\s*-[^-]*-\s*([^()]*?)\s*\(/)[1]`, see the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yG7cT8/1). Group 1 contains the value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the regex using positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=TICKET\ -\ T\d{8}\.\d{4}\ -\ ).*\)
```

Here's regex101 explanation: https://regex101.com/r/6BN16e/1

The query effectively says matching anything after "TICKET - T(8 digits).(4 digits) - ".  You can of course tweak it to your specification.

Here's a tutorial on lookahead and lookbehind that may be helpful: https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: try { $(".problem_description", context).val(clipdata.match(/ (?<=TICKET\ -\ T\d{8}\.\d{4}\ -\ ).*\) /)[0]); } catch (e) {}    I am now getting unexpected quantifier

Comment: Don't forget the g after the second slash. This seems to work for me `const s = "TICKET - T00000000.0000 - Account Security (Company Name...)";
s.match(/(?<=TICKET\ -\ T\d{8}\.\d{4}\ -\ ).*\)/g)[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Use a capture group. In a regex you can use parentheses to mark a capture group. So if you define a pattern where a portion of it marks the text you want to extract, you can wrap that portion in parentheses. The object returned by the match function in most languages is an object that lets you access the values of individual capture groups.

Try this regex I quickly made up: `/[^-]*-[^-]*- ([^(]*)/`

Full example: `var matches = "TICKET - T00000000.0000 - Account Security (Company Name...)".match(/[^-]*-[^-]*- ([^(]*)/)`

Your value will be in `matches[1]`.

It says: start from the beginning, look for anything not a dash, then a dash, then anything not a dash, then another dash, then a space, then capture anything not a left-parenthesis into a capture group.

This one will leave an extra space at the end of the captured group value. Also, it will truncate your value if your value contains a left parenthesis.

Comment: Ty I tried your suggestion and I seem to be getting closer " output was from TICKET to space before (

Comment: Sorry, I had the global flag enabled. I will update my answer.